# Is there a way to get the closed form of $x$ considering $x^2 + 3x = \sqrt{x + 2}$, not using calculator/computer?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would one go about finding the exact answer to $$x^2 + 3x = \sqrt{x + 2}$$
Solving for $x$?

Using paper and pencil to plot a graph, I've found the solution lies at $\approx 0.453$, but I am interested in finding a closed form solution, but I have no idea of how to get there.

Furthermore, trying to solve for $x$ using a calculator or computer gives me what I consider a somewhat messy solution.

Is there a way of getting a "pretty" closed form of $x$ by hand?

Comment: You can, at least in theory, square both sides, use the classial solution for the quartic, and then confirm that you haven't introduced an extraneous solution (e.g., confirm that $x^2+3x$ is positive).

Comment: There is a closed formula for quartic equation, but it is prbably more messy than using some linear approximation for finding the solution, especially if you are asking for preety close and not exact.

Comment: I simply graphed LHS and RHS to confirm that there is a positive solution. It is beside my question.
Additionally I am asking for an exact solution.

Comment: Which one you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depend very much how simple and how accurate can be the closed form.

For example, knowing that the solution is close to $0.5$, we could use a Taylor expansion built around this value. This would give $$x^2 + 3x - \sqrt{x + 2}=\left(\frac{7}{4}-\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}\right)+\left(4-\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}\right)
   \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)+O\left(\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\right)$$  The solution is then $$x=\frac{58+73 \sqrt{10}}{636} \approx 0.454161$$  which is not too bad compared to the exact value $0.453557$

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are sufficient but if you want to be exact;

$a=1,b=6,c=9, d=-1, e=-2$

[Apply them to this formula here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots)

Comment: I guess He said "by hand"

Comment: @DigitalBrain it can be done by hand. It's just impractical.